# MATLAB "CCTV" image processing, contrast filtering/feature detection

Tags: matlab, image-processing, filtering, contrast

I'm a bit of a noob in MATLAB (and image processing in general) and I'm wondering if you can help me with a bit of an issue I'm having. Essentially, I'm given an image of an alley, and then multiple images of the same alley, but with different contrasts and some of the images have a picture of a robber in them. I need to be able to detect the robbers in the images, and run the same code on all of the images (i.e. I'm not allowed to custom-tailor the code for specific images). Here's what I have so far:

```
background = imread('backalley.jpg');
criminal = imread('backalleyX.jpg'); % Where X is the number of the image, there 
%are 16 in total from 0 to 15
J = imhist(background);
K = histeq(criminal,J);
diffImage = abs(double(background)-double(K)); 
thresholdValue = 103;
filteredImage = diffImage > thresholdValue;
```

(Keep in mind I'm still playing around with the thresholdValue)

This leaves me with either a gray image if there isn't a robber, or a black and white image showing some of the features of the robber. The issue I'm having is that three of the 16 images with a very high contrast initially leave me with most of the features of the alley still visible, even after having histogram equalization done. Is there anything I can do to filter these images or adjust the contrast better, that won't cause an issue with the rest of the successfully processed images? Unfortunately since I'm new here I can't post images showing what's going on, sorry.

EDIT: Here is a link to the photobucket album: http://s997.photobucket.com/user/52TulaSKS/library/Image%20Processing

All of the images needing processing are there, as well as the original, and examples of processed images. I gave titles to the important ones (original, ones giving me trouble, and the examples of correctly and incorrectly processed images).

Comment: You could upload the images to .zip through Dropbox or some other free site and provide us with the link. Also, are the images exactly the same with regards to camera position (i.e. just copies of the same image with different contrasts and a robber pasted on)?

Comment: Yes, they are exactly like that. I'll put them on photobucket.

Answer (score 0):

Change your threshold to a higher value.